# Connecting Windows software to angular2 application

Tags: angular, windows, angular-services

I am trying to connect to a windows desktop application from my angular 2 web app where the web app takes input as a file and outputs another file in XML format. The conversion task is of the windows software .
How can this be done ?

Comment: Do you want to hack you users? :)

Comment: no actually I wanted to send a cmd command via the backend of my application .
It is solved now since I did the job using servlet in Java.

Answer (score 0):

Users need to run your windows app which should be listening for connections for instance on port 9999. Then your app must return header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: your-domain`.

I am not sure how its in terms of security but should be possible to do.